# How to fix code in the same line on Return part (React V.18.2.0)

Tags: reactjs

I am a new learner on React app and I found three issues that are:

1.on Return part always  separate to new line (as the picture show), this hard for me to read and learning

2.how can I use foreign language and spacing correctly

3.if you see

, I type "+20,000" but the app always give space on it and the result show  "+20, 200"

[image]

Comment: Please paste the code, not screenshots of the code. What's the filename? Should end in .jsx or .tsx. You shouldn't spaces around your `<p>` tag and other tags. Those red squiggles are errors, mouse over to see the error and fix them 1 by 1.

Comment: yes, you' re right. and I really sorry that picture isn't clear I am very new to post question, and really new learner.  so after I change file name from .js to be .jsx  the app not giving me any spaces, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using JSX syntax, but the resulting formatting is not correct for JSX, and your IDE is showing what looks to be syntax errors. I don't think you're in a JSX file. Change the filename so that it ends in `.jsx`, instead of `.js`. This should fix all the formatting issues, including the part that gets returned, and the spacing of the language used in the JSX, and the spacing of the numbers written in the JSX.

Comment: Thanks a lottttt , It all fixed after I changed file name to .jsx.      

I learn from Youtube and the tutor use JS so I don't know where I was wrong .  Thank you so much you are helping me ,a very new learner.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all guys these issues have fixed by using .jsx

[image]